# How do I submit xcode app to store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made an app using XCode and I'm planning on uploading to Apple iOS store. Only question is:
**How do you do it?!**

I have made all licences however in iTunes connect, I can't find manage apps. I have looked at YouTube videos but they are all too old due to the fact Apple changes their website often.

Can someone please give step by step instructions how to add the actual app?

*Thanks*

Also I am distributing for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log in to [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com)
2. Select My Apps

[image: My Apps]

3. Press the '+' button at the top left and choose "New App" (for iOS) or "New Mac App" (for OS X)

[image: '+' menu]